# How to keep game state not hide when call login facebook (unity facebook sdk 5.1) with build mode Landscape

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

- I create the app using unity-facebook-sdk 5.1 . When i build apk with portrait screen, my game not hide: 
  [portait screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1h09grvhcxegl8/2014-04-23%2014.15.28.png)
  . When i build apk with landscape left mode, my game screen is black: 
  [lanscape screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypjmjmzkq25ophd/2014-04-23%2014.12.37.png)
  . Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is by design, having your app in landscape and login flow in portrait settings cause some problems with rendering - but it looks like you want to use landscape orientation for login as well

you can set it up as you like in android manifest:

```
<activity 
   android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" 
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"         
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

android:theme is Translucent - meaning you game will be visible under login dialog

```
<activity 
   android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" 
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"         
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

android:theme isn't Translucent - login dialog has black background

Comment: I have set up LoginActivity same to you. But my game not avaiable, a black background under confirm facebook popup. Sorry my english not good :(

Comment: Now I get it, you want to remove the black background. Sadly that is not possible in the current version. I made a change, it will go out with next version of the sdk. Hope that helps!